# Do you need an image 'alt' attribute if you have a descriptive filename with hyphens?

Tags: html, image, alt

I have written descriptive filenames including hyphens such as `src="yellow-apple-half-eaten.jpg"`.

Do I really need to also write `alt="Yellow apple half eaten"`?

Also if you are using `<figure><figcaption>` tags do you really also need `<alt="">`?

It's a big hassle when I have hundreds of images. Should I go through the trouble of writing a PHP script to replace the hyphens with spaces for example, or is this not neccessary? I'm using HTML5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have no `alt` content, you are better off having a descriptive than a cryptic file name, because some user agents might use the file name if they have nothing else to work with.

However, that does not mean that you can or should omit the `alt` attribute:

- The `alt` attribute is required ([with exceptions](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/embedded-content-0.html#guidance-for-conformance-checkers); see also below).
- Not all user agents use the file name in case there’s no `alt`.

  HTML5 does not suggest that user agents should use the file name in such a case, see the section under [`img`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/embedded-content-0.html#the-img-element): "If the `src` attribute is set and the `alt` attribute is not".

  And neither should [markup generators](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/embedded-content-0.html#guidance-for-markup-generators) do this (although it doesn’t seem to apply in your case):

  > Markup generators should generally avoid using the image's own file name as the text alternative.
- The image’s file name is not necessarily what makes a good `alt` content (it’s not for what you see on the image, but what’s its purpose in context, which can be very different).
- It’s not very user friendly to read "yellow-apple-half-eaten.jpg" instead of "Half-eaten yellow apple" or even "Yellow apple half eaten".

---

If you can’t provide `alt` content, but you can provide some kind of caption, one of the exceptions might be relevant for you:

You may omit the `alt` attribute if you use a `figure` element with a `figcaption` (for the image caption). See the [conditions](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/embedded-content-0.html#when-a-text-alternative-is-not-available-at-the-time-of-publication).

Comment: @Skyfish: Just to make sure: You’d still need a *suitable* caption for making it accessible, so you don’t "win" anything that way (if you can generate the caption, you could probably also generate the `alt` content instead).

Comment: The comment about the use of the alt attribute with regards to the presence of the figcaption element is incorrect; the information quoted from the HTML specification is in context of the behaviour that web browsers should conform to, not website authors. Note that web browsers are often referred to as 'user agents' in W3C specifications.

Comment: @TristanBailey: Thanks! This applies to the first quote (will remove it), but not to the second one, or do I miss something? *4.7.1.1.16 When a text alternative is not available at the time of publication* does address authors, and validators are not supposed to generate errors for those `img` elements with missing `alt`.

Comment: @unor Sorry, I didn't actually see that section of the specification before now. Section 4.7.1.1.16 is actually in context of website authors. You could replace the first quote with a new one from 4.7.1.1.16

Answer (score 0):

This person tested out the figcaption option and ... it doesn't really replace alt http://www.davidmacd.com/blog/figcaption.html